# Como procurar um valor dentro de um arranjo

Tags: javascript, funções, for, objetos

Eu preciso escrever uma função que me retorne uma lista das habilidades do nome no input do console.log ms não consigo entender esse for-of. Sou novato no javascript e estou desde ontem pulando de artigo em artigo mas não consigo fazer.

```
var usuarios = [
 {
 nome: "Diego",
 habilidades: ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "Redux"]
 },
 {
 nome: "Gabriel",
 habilidades: ["VueJS", "Ruby on Rails", "Elixir"]
 }
];

function funcao(nome1, nome2) {
        for (nome1 of usuarios) {
                return usuarios.habilidades.join();
        for (nome2 of usuarios) {
                return usuarios.habilidades.join();
        };
        };
};

console.log(funcao('Diego', 'Gabriel'));
```

Comment: Queres que retorne 2 arrays ou uma só com todas as habilidades na mesma?

Comment: Qual é a saída esperada para o programa?

Comment: Você saberia fazer utilizando um `for` convencional?

Comment: quero que retorne as duas listas de habilidades

Comment: se está falando sobre o for de looping, não sei como poderia funcionar

Comment: esse é um exercício então eu precisaria fazer com ```for-of``` pra aprender como funciona

Answer (score 1):

Um loop for vai sempre ser interrompido quando chamas o `return`.  Quando tens algo de entrada e queres transformá-lo noutra coisa estás a fazer um mapeamento. É isso que procuras aqui, mapear nomes com a array das suas habilidades.

Deves usar o `map` e dentro de cada iteração procurar o objeto do usuário, e retornar as suas habilidades. Outra dica prática é usares um *spread*  nos argumentos, assim a lógica vai funcionar da mesma maneira independentemente do numero de argumentos (nomes)  que passes a essa função.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
var usuarios = [{
    nome: "Diego",
    habilidades: ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "Redux"]
  },
  {
    nome: "Gabriel",
    habilidades: ["VueJS", "Ruby on Rails", "Elixir"]
  }
];

function funcao(...nomes) {
  return nomes.map(nome => {
    const usuario = usuarios.find(obj => obj.nome === nome);
    return usuario ? usuario.habilidades : [];
  });
};

console.log(funcao('Diego', 'Gabriel'));
```

Para fazer isso com um `for...of` precisas de mais código, mas poderia ser assim:

```js
var usuarios = [{
    nome: "Diego",
    habilidades: ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "Redux"]
  },
  {
    nome: "Gabriel",
    habilidades: ["VueJS", "Ruby on Rails", "Elixir"]
  }
];

function funcao(...nomes) {
  const habilidades = [];
  for (let nome of nomes) {
    const usuario = usuarios.find(obj => obj.nome === nome);
    habilidades.push(usuario ? usuario.habilidades : []);
  }
  return habilidades;
};

console.log(funcao('Diego', 'Gabriel'));
```